# Loading express template with a passed variable returns error `Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, express, express-validator

I have a form and I am trying to validate it with express-validator. When there are no validation errors, I get no error in the console, but when there are validation errors I try to pass them to my EJS template, but it gives me an error in the console. This is my full code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator');

app.listen(8080);

// saytin asuma inch template piti ogtagorcvi
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// MongoDB
let dbUrl = 'mongodb+srv://grig:xxxXXXxxx@cluster0-osvfl.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority';

mongoose.connect(dbUrl ,{useNewUrlParser : true},(err) => { 
   if (err) {
    console.log(err);
   }
});

var schema = new mongoose.Schema({ name: 'string', message: 'string' });
var User = mongoose.model('User', schema);
//

// router
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index');
});

app.use(express.json());
app.post('/send', [
  check('name').isLength({ min: 1 }).withMessage('Անունը չի կարող դատարկ լինել'),
  check('message').isLength({ min: 10 }).withMessage('Նամակը պետք է լինի 10 սիմվոլից ավել')
], (req, res) => {

  // Uxarkel errornery
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    res.render('index',{
      errors: errors
    });
  }

  // Stexcel userin
  User.create({
    name: req.body.name,
    message: req.body.message
  }).then(user => res.json(user));
});
//
```

And here's the error that I'm getting:

```
(node:6244) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:470:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\xampp\htdocs\node\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\xampp\htdocs\node\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (C:\xampp\htdocs\node\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
    at User.create.then.user (C:\xampp\htdocs\node\server.js:51:23)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:6244) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecti
ng a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:6244) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process wit
h a non-zero exit code.
```

I'm new to Node, so can you please explain what causes the error. Thanks.

Comment: why not use `validationResult` also as middleware? and use next(error) to throw errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    res.render('index',{
      errors: errors
    });
  }
else {
  // Stexcel userin
  User.create({
    name: req.body.name,
    message: req.body.message
  }).then(user => res.json(user))
}
```

The else part of code was getting executed, even if there was error, and it was trying to send the response again. thus you were getting that error. Or you can a return when you are sending error, it will resolve the issue.

Comment: So it was trying to create the User even when the validation wasn't passed. Okay, thank you very much.

Comment: Yes correct @GrigoryVolkov, mark it as answer if it resolved your query.